# jquery ajax cant access elements on doc.ready with script

Tags: jquery, ajax

what i have is a page loading some elements with **ajax**, then `$.getScript`
from the script i load, i want to access some of the new `html` elements.

Problem is, if i let the page load and click on element that does whatever i want to do to the elements it works. IF I DO IT **ONLOAD** with `document.ready`, it doesn't work.
 I have seen various 'solutions' around here from people asking similar questions...
all of them just seem too complicated - not that i m afraid of it - but they dont give the 'this should be this way'-feeling, when u know that u have done your work right and by-the-book.

May be someone has a solution\another approach to this problem?

here's relevant code from script that runs 1st:

```
$('#questions').load('ajax/makeGallery.php', { 'tests' : tests });
    $.getScript('scripts/gallery.js', function(){ Gallery.start() });
```

then, supposedly php loaded, in the newly loaded .js file in document.ready i got:

```
questions = $('.slide').length;
$('#s0').fadeIn();
```

both of these commands refer to newly loaded stuff from php - and don't work, although from console, or from an onclick function(after it loads and i click) they work

Comment: If you're using getScript you need to do everything in the callback to that function (in addition to the document being ready).  If that sounds too complicated, don't use getScript.

Comment: this is not what i meant by complicated :)
there is a function in the script i load, and i run it in the success call...

Comment: Show us your code.  It is likely that you aren't waiting for asynchronous operations to finish before trying to use their results.  `$(document).ready()` won't wait for a getScript or an ajax call to complete.  It only works on the loading of the original HTML document, not things loaded by script.